# Display logged in user photo on navbar

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, 2016

Is it possible to display user photo on navbar without adding custom javascript? I found this [link](https://nishantrana.me/2013/10/24/showing-current-logged-in-users-profile-picture-next-to-welcome-menu-in-sharepoint-2013/) but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting profile picture url using rest api and display it on master page nav bar.

The reqest url as follows

```
siteurl/_api/web/currentuser
```

It get complete profile you can build the picture url from the information in resuts. you cna find complete code example in this [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3c5b6eba-a6a8-47ce-877d-d97666ec9708/how-to-display-user-profile-information-in-master-page-header?forum=sharepointdevelopment).

Comment: Thanks for the answer @venkat . Actually I feel like there is a way without using custom code. Because when I look the html output I realize that user name container has _"o365cs-me-tile-nophoto-username"_ class. Nophoto made me think I can enable displaying photo but I couldnt find how to do it.

Comment: Profile picture option is working by default for O365 site. But I will try if I can find a setting for 2016.